# c++ segmentation fault, why using "long long" I dont get an answer?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

Can somebody explain where the mistake is in this code? because when I use parameters like this a=425 b=9631 n=9876543215 I get "exited,segmentation fault code 139" :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void ivedimas(long long &n, long long &a, long long &b);
long long fib(long long n, long long a, long long b); 
void isvedimas(long long ats);
int main()
{
    long long n,a,b;
    ivedimas(n,a,b);
    isvedimas(fib(n,a,b));
    return 0;
}

void ivedimas(long long &n, long long &a, long long &b)
{
    cin>>a>>b>>n;
}
long long fib(long long n,long long a, long long b)
{
  long long c=b-a;
  if (n==2)
  return c;
  return fib(n-1,b,c);
}
void isvedimas(long long ats)
{
    cout<<ats<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow seems likely. Is your recursion not terminating?

Comment: Even if it does *eventually* stop the recursion, it will have called itself `9876543213` times! That's gonna eat up a *lot* of stack.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Good point!

Comment: I too agree, that stack overflow is the likely culprit. Stack is typically in the order of 1-8MB of size, hence creating `9876543213` stack frames, most likely, depletes it, and you get segmentation fault. Consider switching to iterative algorithm.

Comment: With `9876543215` function calls you likely exhaust stack space and crash. Each recursive call requires the setup of a separate function stack. (which is why recursion must be treated carefully to insure it doesn't repeat so many times you run out of space)

Comment: long long longlong( long long Long, long long llong, long long longlonglong )

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow: every time the function calls itself it adds to the stack, so this solution works for small numbers, but anything too large it will fail.

Iterative solution:

```
long long fib(long long n, long long a, long long b)
{
    if (n == 0) {return 0;}
    if (n == 1) {return 1;}
    long long t = 0;
    long long j = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int k = j;
        j += t;
        t = k;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't c++ (or its most popular compilers, to be exact) support tail call optimization?

Comment: Are you asking why the function has parameters @sp2danny ?  And i fixed the error with the repeated i.  I just copied the function signature from the OP

Comment: @Tasos TCO is typically disabled in debug build.

Comment: TCO breaks tracebacks. There's no reason singly-recursive algorithms (since they are *always* easy to transform by hand) unless you're a purist who doesn't deal with real-world computers.

Comment: @sp2danny yes, in g++ it's -O2 and above I think. Not sure if I'd suggest this as an answer, but it's useful to know, surely.

Comment: Funny how `a` and `b` are unused in the algorithm.

Comment: Is it kidding ?  If giving the function code, please make sure it works correctly.

Comment: If `n` requires a `long long`, then so does `i` and `k`. Furthermore, with the parameters in the OP example, the result is negative.

Answer (score 2):

This recursive version of Fibonacci is not good with large number. Each time it's called the recursion the stack increse and never decrese till the end. So you just terminate the process memory before the result is return.

You can try an iterative solution.

Answer (score -1):

thank you, this is the solution:)) every 6th number in the sequence is the same :) 
e.g. 10,8,-2,-10,-8,2|10,8,-2,-10,-8,2...

```
long long fib(long long n,long long a, long long b)
{ long long c=a;
if (n==0) return a;
if (n%6==1) return b;
  for (int i=1;i<n%6;i++)
  {
    c=b-a;
    a=b;
    b=c;
  }
  return c;
}
```